# RMarkdown: How to change headline in table of contents in R Markdown?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

When I'm using the `toc: yes` command, the document contains "Content" as the headline of the table of contents. Due to the fact that I want to write this document in german, I also want to change the headline of the table of contents to the equivalent german word. Any suggestions on how to change this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With this YAML header that includes LaTeX-Package babel, it works for me:

```
---
title: "TOC in German"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: yes
---
```

Answer (score 14):

This in your YAML should also work:

`header-includes:
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}`

Answer (score 4):

You can also make use of babel simply specifying in the YAML header the "lang" field. For example:

```
---
lang: de-DE
title: "Ausgefallener Titel"
toc: 1
---
```

I.e., you can use the "lang" field and specify your desired language-and-country code. For example, de-DE, en-US, etc. (Of course, the corresponding babel package for that language should be installed, or you'll get an error).