# using knitr/rmarkdown to produce outputs in multiple natural languages (from a data.frame)

Tags: r, translation, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to produce a document in `rmarkdown` that can produce outputs in multiple (natural) languages, it should extract the text in one of the translations from a `data.frame`.

The `data.frame` should contain a column for each language and translations of the same text on each row, e.g.

```
EN <- c('title', 'author', 'a sentence')
FR <- c('titre', 'auteur', 'une phrase')
translation <- data.frame(EN, FR, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

It should be possible to format the text extracted, e.g.

```
# [desired code here]
```

Should produce and rmarkdown title.

**EDIT**: Ideally we would be able to specify the language in the YAML front-matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this as follows: (please see the ps for more latex-options)

Why? The YAML header is evaluated line by line :) - see [here](https://itsalocke.com/blog/r-quick-tip-parameter-re-use-within-rmarkdown-yaml/)

````
---
params:
  lang: EN
lang: "`r switch(params$lang, DE = 'de-DE', EN = 'en-US')`"
output: pdf_document
toc: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
lswitch <- function(lang, ...){
  switch(lang, ..., stop("No translation privided"))
}
```

# `r lswitch(params$lang, DE = "Dies ist der Titel", EN = "this is the title")`

`r lswitch(params$lang, 
DE = "Die folgende Abbildung zeigt die Funktion $f(x) = x^2$", 
EN = "The following plot shows the function $f(x) = x^2$"
)
`

```{r plot1_cap, include=FALSE}
plot1_cap <- lswitch(params$lang, DE = "Tolle Abbildung", EN = "Great plot")
```
```{r plot1, fig.cap= plot1_cap}
plot(seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50), seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)^2, 
     type = "l", xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)")
```

# `r lswitch(params$lang, DE = "Zweiter Titel", EN = "Second Title")`

`r lswitch(params$lang, 
DE = "Zweiter Abschnitt", 
EN = "Second paragraph"
)
`
````

This results in

[image]

If you change the yaml-header to

```
---
params:
  lang: DE
lang: "`r switch(params$lang, DE = 'de-DE', EN = 'en-US')`"
output: pdf_document
toc: 1
---
```

you get

[image]

**PS: More Latex options**

If you want to use a specific language package you can add the following in your YAML header: (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163496/3301344)

```
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
---
```

For e.g. using chinese have a look at: http://felixfan.github.io/RMarkdown-Chinese-PDF/

Comment: I actually figured out the line thing, but the idea of using this in combination with `rownames` is very elegant

Comment: it would be amazing if we could define the language in the YAML front-matter, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have a look here on how to do it: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html

Comment: thanks, I looked at the documentation but clearly not closely enough. I have added this to the question in an edit.

Comment: I got the error "object 'params' not found"

Answer (score -1):

As you opened a question here, I also add my answer to you. You can use `cat` in chunk with `results='asis'`, and compare your table of translated language with the content of the formatted chunk.
This way, the original text is highlighted in the chunk (in rstudio) so that you can easily find your text in your long code. With inline Rcode, everything is the same colour, which is not easy to see.

````
```{r TransRef}
# Translation reference
tr.orig <- translation[,"EN"]
```


```{r MyFirstParagraph, results='asis', verbatim=TRUE}
cat('
# ', translation[tr.orig == "title", lang], '

', translation[tr.orig == "a sentence", lang], '   

- ', translation[tr.orig == "author", lang], '
', sep = "")
```
````